# Why does recursive mode on chmod do everything but recursion?

Tags: bash, unix, centos, chmod

`chmod -R 775 *.cgi` only changes permissions on the files in the current directory, the files in the subdirectory don't get modified at all. This is the exact same functionality as simply doing `chmod 775 *.cgi`. I have seen people use solutions such as with `find` and whatnot. Ok great, but why does -R mode even exist if it doesn't even accomplish anything?

Comment: Cool thanks for all the answers. The answers explaining using find was useful, but I selected msw's answer because I was more curious about what the -R does. I only chose msw's instead of Matthew's since msw's was earlier slightly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably because you have no directories named `*.cgi`. Quoth the [manual](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/chmod.html):

> **-R** Recursively change file mode bits. For each file operand that names a
>   directory, chmod shall change the file
>   mode bits of the directory and all
>   files in the file hierarchy below it.

For example:

```
$ ls -R
.:
a  a.c  b.c  c.c

./a:
a.c  b.c  sub

./a/sub:
a.c  b.c  
$ chmod -R 444 *.c
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 3 msw msw 4096 2010-08-12 18:07 a
-r--r--r-- 1 msw msw    0 2010-08-12 18:07 a.c
-r--r--r-- 1 msw msw    0 2010-08-12 18:07 b.c
-r--r--r-- 1 msw msw    0 2010-08-12 18:07 c.c
$ : directory a not affected
$ chmod -R u-w a    
$ ls -l a
-r-xr-xr-x 1 msw msw    0 2010-08-12 18:07 a.c
-r-xr-xr-x 1 msw msw    0 2010-08-12 18:07 b.c
dr-xr-xr-x 3 msw msw 4096 2010-08-12 18:07 sub
$ ls -l a/sub
-r-xr-xr-x 1 msw msw    0 2010-08-12 18:07 a.c
-r-xr-xr-x 1 msw msw    0 2010-08-12 18:07 b.c
$ : got em
```

Answer (score 10):

`-R` tells `chmod` to recurse into any directories that are given as arguments.

If you say `chmod -R 775 *.cgi`, the shell will expand `*.cgi` into a list of files which match that pattern, and pass that as the list of arguments - so `chmod` isn't being asked to look into any other directories.

(It *will* recurse into any *directory* which matches `*.cgi`...)

Comment: Oh gotcha. So it's useful for recursively changing all the files under a certain directory.

Answer (score 7):

To accomplish what you want try

```
find . -name '*.cgi' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

Here `find` generates a list of all the file with a `.cgi` ending from the current directory downward, and passes that list to `xargs` which applies `chmod` to each one.

Answer (score 4):

`*.cgi` is expanded by your shell to a list of all the file names in the current directory ending in `.cgi`. Then the shell calls `chmod` with this list of filenames.

`chmod` looks at all those file names it got from the shell, changes there modes and would recurse if some of them were directories. But probably none of them are, so there is nothing to recurse.

To find all cgi files in the current directory and its subdirectories, and run `chmod` on them, you could do:

```
find . -name '*.cgi' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775
```

Comment: This answer is the same dmckee

Answer (score 3):

`*` is a shell builtin, while -R is a command line option. So `chmod` will never get `*` as an argument.

Put the case that foo0.cgi and foo1.cgi are the contents of the directory. If you type `chmod -R o+r *.cgi` then `chmod` will get the '-R', 'o+r', 'foo0.cgi' and 'foo1.cgi' as arguments.

What you want to do can be accomplished easily:

```
find . -iname '*.cgi' | xargs chmod 755
```

Comment: This answer is the same dmckee